# ELK , Filebeat Setup on Local Machine , Logstash is not working, lumberjack protocal error

Tags: elastic-stack, querydsl, log-analysis, kibana-6

I'm trying to learn ELK stack and as per recommendation, I  have downloaded the latest ELK stack ( 6.4.2 version ) and running all the application on my local machine along with Filebeat.
When, I'm pointing filbeat directly to Elastic Search, I'm able to get the data in the Kibana dashboard but when I'm pointing it to Logstash and then logstash to Elastic search. An error is coming in the filebeat logs where its not able to forward the event due to lumberjack error.
I read several pages about this error and verified the host and port , I tried the value of the host to both IP address and "localhost" on port 5044 at filebeat but its not resolving.
I have tried setting SSL value to true ( and generated the self signed certificate and used that ) and false both  but that also didn't work.

Can please someone guide me what should I be looking at to get this going ?

Also, I want to use regex in the Kibana query and create variable to do further operation on those, is that possible in Kibana ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please post your filebeat, logstash config and filebeat error log entry.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it worked .. I hadn't use filebeat propectors tag in the filebeat.yml and the input.conf was having incorrect 'host' tag name